# How to redirect the data from "vscode.previewHtml" in VSCode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

The obvious way is written in [Working with the HTML preview](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api-commands#_working-with-the-html-preview), to use `<a href="command:foo">some</a>` link, so how to send data to the base running program without clicking links? I want to make some seamless extension between editor and previewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few possible ways:

- Open a local communications channel between your extension and the page. The extension could setup a simple server for example that the webview hits. This is best if you have lots of data to send or need to support more complex scenarios.
- Inside the webview, you can instead post a message simulating a click with a command. Here's what VSCode's built-in markdown extension does for example:

  ```
  window.parent.postMessage({
     command: 'did-click-link',
     data: `command:_markdown.revealLine?${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(args))}`
  }, 'file://');
  ```

The second approach is pretty hacky but it works well to just trigger events every so often.

We are also considering a better API for this. Please [let us know if you have any thoughts or suggestions](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues) for this

Comment: Thank you :) Indeed sending back the message from previewHtml is so often that it's good if there is a more clear way...